# Meteorjs - Passing data context to Template Rendered function?

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-helper

I have these data context and I want to use JQuery to set the selected value in the  tag based on the value.

I am having problem passing the return data from the helpers into the Template.Rendered function.

is there any way of doing that?

Helpers

```
Template.studentSetting.helpers({
  values: function(){
    return Basics.findOne({userId:Meteor.userId()});
  }
});
```

Rendered function

```
Template.studentSetting.rendered = function(){
 //I want to use the "values" helper data here and perform some jquery code based on that?? 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-call-helper-from-another-helper-event-and-tpl-callbacks/5038/2), I would advise doing what mpowaga suggests in the thread and just define the helper outside:

```
var valuesFunc = function () {
  return Basics.findOne({userId:Meteor.userId()});
};

Template.studentSetting.helpers({
  values: valuesFunc
});

Template.studentSetting.onRendered(function(){
  var values = valuesFunc();
});
```

Comment: how can i get the values inside?

Comment: Just assign what your function returns: `var values = this.__helpers.get('values').call();`

Comment: Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at null.<anonymous> (setting.js?8333356b073416c5904ab107eb6ae043b760b98a:64)
    at template.js:116
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:437)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:112)
    at null.<anonymous> (template.js:205)
    at view.js:104
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:523)
    at view.js:103
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:468)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)

Comment: yeap i also getting same.. :(

Comment: I guess the first solution dont work. Just go for the second solution that @BraveKenny advised: you define a function *outside* your `Rendered` function (at the beginning of your file), and you call it both in the `Rendered` function and your helper.

Comment: Can @BraveKenny edit the answer to the 2nd solution, the 1st one doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `studentSettings` template with an argument like this:

```
{{> studentSettings inheritedValues=values}}
```

You can then access it into your `Rendered` function like this:

```
Template.studentSetting.rendered = function(){
 var values = this.data.inheritedValues;
 console.table(values);
}
```

Comment: Apparently, OP wants to call `Template.studentSetting` helper from within its own `rendered` hook, not its parent template's helper

Comment: I need to get the values within that docs, whateverway possible