# Can I use a global helper to pass data into onRendered?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to set a variable in the onRendered callback equal to the value from the `active` global helper.  My global helpers are defined as follows:

client/lib/helpers.js

```
//all possible calculations//
getResults = function(valuationId,targetId){
    var valuation = Valuations.findOne({_id: valuationId});
    var targetTicker = Companies.findOne({_id:targetId}).ticker;
    var targetData = CompaniesData.findOne({ticker: targetTicker});
    return {
        peFy1: targetData.epsFy1 * valuation.priceEarningsFy1,
        peFy2: targetData.epsFy2 * valuation.priceEarningsFy2
        //more//
    }
};

//choose one value from above, based on several other variables//
Template.registerHelper('active',function(){
    var valuationId = this._id;
    var targetId = this.targetId;
    var valuationPeriod = this.valuationPeriod;
        switch (valuationPeriod) {
            case "FY1"
                return getResults(valuationId, targetId).peFy1;
                break;
            case "FY2":
                return getResults(valuationId, targetId).peFy2;
                break;
        //more cases//
```

I can get and use a single value directly from `getResults` with the last line below.

```
Template.ValuationBase.onRendered (function () {
    var targetId = Template.parentData(0).targetId;
    var valuationId = Template.parentData(0)._id;
    var valuationActive = getResults(valuationId,targetId).peFy1;
```

But I can't figure out how to get the value resulting from logic in the `active` helper.  I thought it would be `var valuationActive = active();` but that returns `not defined`.  I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31559435/4168250) but it seems to be creating the function in the template JS, rather than referring to a helper.

I'm sure this is a basic mistake in how I am calling the function.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Blaze._globalHelpers.active()` to refer to your global helper `active` from javascript anywhere on the client.

I would add (again) that relying on `this` to pass the data context for your global helper is risky. You're assuming that context will always be set correctly no matter what. You can defend yourself from this assumption with:

```
Template.registerHelper('active',function(id){
  var valuationId = id || this._id; // use the arg if provided, otherwise rely on 'this'
  ...
});
```

Comment: Retracted previous comment as I'm starting to see data coming through with `UI._globalHelpers`, just need to fix how I am passing parameters, which I'm sure goes to your second point.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Bren Use `Blaze._globalHelpers` instead. `UI` is deprecated.

Comment: And UI replaced the previous thing that was deprecated. Neither `Blaze._globalHelpers` nor `UI._globalHelpers` are documented though. Where was this change announced if anywhere?